# Can we still use SiteDotCom metadata after enabling ExperienceBundle?

Tags: community, metadata-api, lightning-community, site.com

We've activated [ExperienceBundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_migrate_expbundle.htm) metadata for communities. However, there's a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YpD0QAK) with it that is preventing us from actually being able to deploy using that metadata. In order to avoid having to make manual changes until they fix it, **can I revert back to just using SiteDotCom in my deployments?**

The documentation doesn't seem to be very clear on this

> After you enable ExperienceBundle, Metadata API calls (retrieve and
>   deploy) and Salesforce DX operations (pull, push, and status) use the
>   ExperienceBundle type instead of SiteDotCom.

However, it doesn't seem to imply there's anything stopping us from specifying SiteDotCom to pull and deploy from the API. Only thing is, I won't really be able to tell if it's actually kept up-to-date with community changes since activating the new metadata type.

I pulled the SiteDotCom metadata and the lastModifiedDate on the Community I'm looking at seems to imply it hasn't changed with our recent changes which makes me think it's no longer an accurate representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking to the Product Team, Here is what is recommend.

- Disable experience bundle in settings
- Retrieve the sitedotcom metadata type
- Deploy the sitedotcom and other dependencies.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I can't believe I didn't think about disabling it again - I just assumed it was one of those all or none settings! Is there any info on what enable/disable actually does (might be another question!)

Comment: Not sure but will check internally! Reach out to me for any feedback. Email shared!!

Answer (score 2):

**The answer is yes.**

I did get word from my support case where Tier 3 said `SiteDotCom` is still up-to-date even with `ExperienceBundle` enabled and I asked that they include that as a *workaround* for the [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YpD0QAK) in the question as a way to get this documented (*not sure if they will actually add this*).

Regardless, the above prompted me to feel it was worth doing some test runs. I was still concerned by the `lastModifiedDate`, but I also found this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cMWgQAM) which seems to confirm that manually published changes (which is what we did) don't accurately get reflected in the metadata types related to Community.

I deployed the SiteDotCom metadata to a sandbox and it appears it contained changes that happened after the lastModifiedDate so that confirms the metadata type is still an accurate representation of your community even after you've enabled ExperienceBundle regardless of what the timestamp says.

Also to note, the lastModifiedDate changes once you do deploy SiteDotCom in your target environment.

Comment: Please reach out to me at mohith.shrivastava@salesforce.com for any feedback on communities metadata. We are looking to improve the experience.